# Is it possible to specify which Before method runs in JUnit, and if so, how?

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a test suite which tests two different things in the same class. I have a before method that initialises some fields for the test methods to use. However, I have a group of test methods that uses the first set of field, and another group that uses the second, but not the first. I know it's possible to split the before action over different before methods, but is it also possible to specify which one runs before each test?

Concrete example:

```
@Before
public void before1() {...}

@Before
public void before2() {...}

@Test
public void test1() {
    //Only before1 runs
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    //Only before2 runs
}
```

This is a simple representation, but I have much more tests that use either of these befores.

Comment: There is no guarantee on the order of a `@Before` executing just as there's no guarantee on a `@Test` order of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you've stated in your question is pointing to splitting up your tests into 2 separate classes.  I am guessing that the two groups you have are testing distinct features of your code and may even have some commonality in the test names.  Take all of the tests that require `before1` into a test class and all the tests that require `before2` into another test class.   You can name these new test classes according to the grouping of behaviour you're testing.

For example if half of your tests are for success scenarios and half are testing failure scenarios, put these into classes named something like `FooSucceedsTest` and the failures into `FooFailsTest`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee on the order of a `@Before` executing just as there's no guarantee on a `@Test` order of execution.

The solution is to do any setup a test is dependent on in the `@Test` itself and use the `@Before` for common setup before test execution.